# Read the annotations on a CT image

Tags: image, dicom

I have a **CT** **image** but some of the **annotations** i am not sure what do they **stand for**. These annotations are the following:

1) PP: HFS;

2) PRE

3) TI: 821.00 msec;

4) SP: -1372.30

5) 00564489, is this a patient ID?

Anybody can help me about this? Image can also be read [here]

Comment: *PP: HFS* is definitely *Patient Position: Head First, Supine*. *TI* might be *Inversion time*, although I am not sure if that would be relevant for a CT image. The number series is evidently the patient ID.

Comment: I think Anders has it right, but I must comment that you shouldn't be posting patient health information here! I'm not sure what the laws are in Korea, but this would not be good in the US.

Answer (score 0):

1) PP: HFS : This is Patient Position: Head First, Supine

2) PRE: This could mean Previous study

3) TI : 821.00 msec  - Could be Time Interval

4) SP: -1372.30 - This is Slice Position

5) 00564489, is this a patient ID?  -- if this is next to patient name on right top corner.

Your best option is to get the user guide or help documentation of the application you are investigating. It should list what each label represents.